# Swift - change image of UIImageView dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a normal `UIImage` and a `list` of images. My goal is that every few seconds the image changes automatically with some sort of never ending loop through my `imageList`.

This is my list:

```
let images: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "avocadoImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "beerImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "bikeImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "christmasImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "dressImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "giftImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "goalImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "rollerImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "shirtImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "shoeImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "travelImage")!,     
    ]
```

I tried this:

```
 NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: "ChangeImage", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But I don't know how I can loop through my array over and over again.

Comment: Down the list or randomly?

Comment: random would be nice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the following instance properties:

```
private let imageView = UIImageView()
private var imageTimer: Timer?
private let images = [
    UIImage(named: "avocadoImage"),
    UIImage(named: "beerImage"),
    UIImage(named: "bikeImage"),
    UIImage(named: "christmasImage"),
    UIImage(named: "dressImage"),
    UIImage(named: "giftImage"),
    UIImage(named: "goalImage"),
    UIImage(named: "rollerImage"),
    UIImage(named: "shirtImage"),
    UIImage(named: "shoeImage"),
    UIImage(named: "travelImage"),
]
```

Then start the timer and add it to the run loop (likely `viewDidLoad`):

```
private func startImageTimer() {
    imageTimer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        imageView.image = images.randomElement()
    }

    RunLoop.main.add(imageTimer!, forMode: .common)
}
```

Then you'll want to observe when the app enters and exits the background so you can toggle the timer. Add these observers (likely `viewDidLoad`):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(backgroundHandler), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foregroundHandler), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc private func backgroundHandler() {
    imageTimer?.invalidate()
    imageTimer = nil
}

@objc private func foregroundHandler() {
    startImageTimer()
}
```

Comment: your answer is working perfectly but I am not quite sure if the timer actually stops. How does `didEnterBackground` work? Because I just move my `View` out of the screen with `.transform` but I do not change the `ViewController` or  `delete` subview. So does it actually stop when it moves out of the screen?

Comment: `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` notifies you when the app itself enters the background (i.e. the user pushed the home button on their iPhone to leave your app but did not kill the app). And then the other notification notifies you when the app has come back onto their screen. You should start and stop timers as the app enters and exits the background. However, in your case, you may also choose to start and stop the timer as the view controller enters and exits from view. That I have not incorporated in my answer.

Comment: If this view controller doesn't have a permanent lifespan, then I would stop and `nil` the timer in the view controller's `deinit { ... }` so it does not linger in the run loop when the view controller is no longer alive.

Comment: alright I get that. In my case I have `button` that lets the `View` appear. But I am having an issue here because the timer only starts after I let the `View` appear the 2nd time. (this occurs if I don't implement `startImageTimer()` inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Is the timer inside a plain `UIView` or inside a `UIViewController`?

Comment: `UIViewController`

Comment: I don't know how you have it all set up and how this view controller is being brought into view, how long it's alive, how it dies, etc. Therefore, you're going to have to play around with it until you understand this controller's lifecycle. What I would do is in each lifecycle event of the view controller (`viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear`, `deinit`, etc.), print something in there and see how this view controller operates and then decide where is best to start and stop the timer.

Comment: But no matter what you decide on, make sure to start and stop it when the app enters and exits the background.

Comment: To help you out with the view controller's lifecycle: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller. Scroll down to `Managing the View` and `Responding to View-Related Events`

Comment: I found my mistake, it is working perfectly now thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203483/discussion-between-chris-and-bsod).

Comment: @bsod I am pretty sure you are capturing `self` (the view controller) strongly in the timer's closure. And self holds the timer. So there is a reference cycle, meaing the timer will never stop,